# Create .Net library with sub-assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

How can I create a dll in .NET that has sub-assemblies?

For example, if I have a project "MyUtilities", I'd like to create a sub-assembly "MyUtilities.EmailUtilities" with classes specific to emailing.  Then, in a new project, when I add a reference to the compiled dll of MyUtilities, I could access the EmailUtilities classes using code like:

```
MyUtilities.EmailUtilities.EmailBlaster eBlaster = new MyUtilities.EmailUtilities.EmailBlaster
```

Comment: Just name the project accordingly...

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I'd like to have one project, and one dll to reference.  My project is named "MyUtilities", but I'd like to have different classes grouped into sub-namespaces as some below have suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should make a single ordinary project with a subfolder called `EmailUtilities`.
This will create a separate **namespace** containing those classes.

Comment: I tried this, but the EmailBlaster class was accessible using MyUtilities.EmailBlaster, not MyUtilities.EmailUtilities.EmailBlaster.  Adding "Namespace EmailUtilities" in the code of the EmailBlaster class as thecoup and Joe suggested worked.  Separating my classes into folders by namespace does make sense though, thanks!

Comment: Then you need to update the `namespace` line. It only gets set by default when you first add the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up namespaces and assemblies. They have nothing to do with each other. Namespaces can span across multiple assemblies, and assemblies can have multiple namespaces.

What you're describing is just sub-namespaces, which can be done all in code.

Either:

```
namespace MyUtilities
{
    namespace EmailUtilities
    {
         // Your code here
    }
}
```

Or, more commonly:

```
namespace MyUtilities.EmailUtilities
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create sub-assemblies in .NET, at least not the way you are thinking about. They only thing remotely close is [satellite assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but that is not what you want. What you should do is organize your classes into separate namespaces. Note that the namespaces can be nested.